# read a text file and iterate through it to create a CSV based on words

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file that looks like below.

```
Name : ValueA
Age: 23
Height: 178cm
Name : ValueB
Age: 22
Height: 168cm
Weight: 80Kg
Name : ValueC
Age: 40
Height: 188cm
IQ: 150
```

I am looking for code to iterate through the and create a csv with text starting with Name as first column, and other properties as other columns.

It should look something like below:

| Name | Age | Height | Weight | IQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ValueA | 23 | 178cm | NA | NA |
| ValueB | 22 | 168cm | 80kg | NA |
| ValueC | 40 | 188cm | NA | 150 |

All Names have unique values

Comment: You have this data in a text file and convert it into a csv file?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I think you can just save this file as csv manually. Why do you want to use python?

Comment: Can we assume "Stuff" is always the same keyword but Property 1, Property 2 etc. can be any string?

Comment: @Ssayan Updated the example. Hope it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below parsing (**EDIT**: addressing the columns order issue in comment):

```py
import pandas as pd

# assuming your file is called "test.txt"
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    t = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Organise data
stuff = {}
ordered_columns = ["Name"]
index = 0
for line in t:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Name": value}
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    else:
        stuff[current_key][key] = value
        # Keep track of the order the columns appear
        if key not in ordered_columns:
            ordered_columns.append(key)

# create dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame(stuff).T
# Apply the column orders (order in which they appear in the file)
result_df = result_df[ordered_columns]

# Create CSV
result_df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

OUTPUT:
[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Hey mate the columns seems to be getting sorted alphabetically instead of the way you have shown in the results.

Comment: It may be due to the version of Python you have. The DataFrame is created by a dictionnary and keys (here column name) are not ordered. They way it is displayed has been changed in different versions of Python so it may be that. Anyway, a quick fix would be to define the column order you want in the end. I'll update my answer.